# No module named 'pydirectinput'

Tags: python, pip, pyautogui

I'm trying to run this file with cmd using command:

```
python main.py
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path of the file\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pydirectinput
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydirectinput'
```

I'm also trying to run this file as an exe using auto-py-to-exe, but it just closes itself when I run it. It might be because of this.
How do I fix this?

I've tried reinstalling PyDirectInput, pip, both from console and PyCharm. The python interpeter in PyCharm with all of the plugins is located in the folder where the **main.py** is. I really don't know what else can I try.

Comment: Nope, I've tried that also before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that just reinstalling the module works.
I deleted it from interpreter folder and downloaded it again with:

```
python -m pip install pydirectinput
```

Comment: It was probably an older version of the module that was causing the error.